# The page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web

I used RewriteOptions to add "/" to end all urls, but when publishing to the iis server I get a "page does not redirect correctly" error.

i using this

```
var options = new RewriteOptions() //add '/' to end of url
        .AddRedirect("(.*[^/])$", "$1/")
        .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();
            app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: Would you kindly check your middleware order? It should be in these manner, `app.UseStaticFiles();` and then `app.UseRouting();`. In addition, what error you are getting? Does the error persist in local environment as well?

Comment: Yes, I used your words.
I get the error only on the iis server
You can see the error at: https://pdftoconverter.com

Comment: I have checked your link its looping, and I got this `https://pdftoconverter.com/` so the expected behavior would be without  slash `/` right? I mean `https://pdftoconverter.com` like this?

Comment: No, I want / to be placed at the end of the urls

Comment: But I found it has `/` end of it like this `https://pdftoconverter.com/`

Comment: Yes, the URL is correct, but I think the redirect error is from iis

Comment: Have you installed [`URL Rewrite Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module#about-the-url-rewrite-module) in IIS? Please [`download from here`](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). It would resolve your issue.

Comment: Rewrite is currently installed on IIS, I think to solve the problem I need to define a new rule for rewrite in IIS
Can you suggest a suitable pattern?

Comment: Well, thanks for your response. May I know your requirement? What do you want to acheive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you suggest a suitable pattern?

Well, assuming you have already installed [URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)from the below official site. Here is the reference for you.

[image]

**Configure URL Rewrite Pattern and Rules:**

As, so far your requirement is to add additional `slash /` of your website, Thus,you can set this `(.*[^/])$` pattern on your URL Rewrite module in IIS as below:

[image]

**Steps for configuration:**

1. Select your site in IIS
2. Double Click on URL Rewrite under HTTP Features Table
3. Click On Add Rules(s) top right
4. Select Append Or remove the trainin slash symbol
5. Select Appended if does not exist from the dropdown
6. Click OK

**Note:** You can customize your rules as well. If you encounter any concern on this you can have a look below screen capture how to do it.

**Output:**
[image]

If you still need more further assistance, you could have look on our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)